# When to materialize content of http response in akka-http?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Let's imagine proxy application based on akka-streams and akka-http which takes (as TCP server) messages in some home-grown format, makes http requests from them, asks some other http server, converts http response back to home-grown format and replies back to the client. Simpified code below:

```
// as Client part 
val connPool = Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[CustHttpReq](someHost, somePort)

val asClientFlow = Flow[CustHttpReq]
  .via (connPool)
  .map (procHttpResp)

def procHttpResp (p: (Try[HttpResponse], CustHttpReq)): Future[ByteString] = {
  val (rsp, src) = p
  rsp match {
    case Success(response: HttpResponse) =>
      for (buf <- cvtToHomeGrown (response, src)) 
          yield buf
    case Failure(ex) => ... 
  }
}

def cvtToHomeGrown (rsp: HttpResponse): Future[ByteString] = {
  rsp.entity.dataBytes.runWith (Sink.fold (ByteString.empty)(_ ++ _))
    .map (cvtToHomeGrownActually) // has signature String => ByteString
}

// as Server part
val parseAndAskFlow = Flow[ByteString]
  .via(Framing.delimiter(
    ByteString('\n'))
  .map (buf => cvtToCustHttpReq (buf))
  .via (asClientFlow)  // plug-in asClient part, the problem is here

val asServerConn: Source[IncomingConnection, Future[ServerBinding]] = Tcp().bind("localhost",port)

asServerConn.runForeach (conn => conn.handleWith(parseAndAskFlow)
```

The problem is that conn.handleWith requires Flow[ByteString,ByteString,], but http client code (rsp.entity.dataBytes...) returns Future[ByteSring], so parseAndAskFlow has Flow[ByteString,Future[ByteString],] type and I have no idea where to complete it better. I even guess it's not a good idea at all as far as all of these are streams and Await somethere will stop nice async processing, but code is not compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mapAsync` instead of `map` to change the type of `asClientFlow` to `Flow[CustHttpReq, ByteString]`:

```
val asClientFlow: Flow[CustHttpReq, ByteString] =
  Flow[CustHttpReq]
    .via(connPool)
    .mapAsync(1)(procHttpResp)
```

Then `parseAndAskFlow` can be of type `Flow[ByteString, ByteString]`:

```
val parseAndAskFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString] =
  Flow[ByteString]
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"))
    .map(cvtToCustHttpReq)
    .via(asClientFlow)
```

Comment: Bingo! You made my day. One more round of streams learning helix was passed. Thank you very much.